# Impossible to uninstall outlook addin multiuser x64

Tags: installation, windows-installer, outlook-addin

I'm having trouble with my outlook addin x64 for multi user.

The installation process works fine, and the addin works correctly, but when I try to uninstall it, I got those three messages box :

[image: first error : Permission denied on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WwanSvc]

(english translation: Permission denied on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WwanSvc)

[image: 1: 1101 2: C:\Config.Msi\fcf43f7.rbs 3: 2]
[image: 1: 1712]

And the addin does not want to unistall.
Basically, my problem is the same than this one (http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4EB922D9.1090903%40mistoll.de&forum_name=wix-users ).

The explanation, apparently, comes from a registry key that refers [TARGETDIR], but I need it ! The guilty key content is : [TARGETDIR]/myaddin.vsto|vstolocal.

I tried adding 'file:///' (as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070586/create-registry-in-both-wow6432node-and-normal-hive ), but then :

- the addin does not work
- the uninstallation process "works", but still shows another message box (the same than the first one, but on another registry key). The addin is then surprisingly correctly unistalled despite the message box

I should also add that this only append on x64 machines for multiusers. I developped other installers for x86 and/or single user that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

1. The SYSTEM account sometimes loses access to parts of the system. I don't know why this happens, but installs etc run with the SYSTEM account so check the access on that registry item. Also, it's mentioning a rollback file, and that implies that Windows is trying to clean up a failed install or otherwise doing something with it after a reboot, and it can't see that file (1712 error) and that may also be a SYSTEM account access issue.  I have also seen issues with the `config.msi` folder, so again see if SYSTEM has access. If you search for `config.msi` issues you'll find some.

   I have no idea why the uninstall wants to look at the auto config service.
2. The errors might happen if somebody "cleaned" up the `\windows\installer` folder that is used to cache MSI files, patches and other install related stuff.