# How to manually uninstall TortoiseHg?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, tortoise-hg

I want to uninstall tortoisehg 3.1.1 from a Windows 7 machine (64 bit), but the setup program fails with the error "unable to write to Config.Msi", similar to one of the error messages from this question: [Impossible to uninstall outlook addin multiuser x64](https://superuser.com/questions/712810/impossible-to-uninstall-outlook-addin-multiuser-x64/712858#712858)

Here is what I've tried:

1. Changing the permissions of Config.Msi so everyone has full control.
   Made no difference.
2. Uninstalling from control panel add/remove programs. It just results
   in the same error.
3. Reinstalling TortoiseHg again, on top of existing install. However,
   the setup program is "helpful" and detects that an install already
   exists. So it only gives the options to change/repair/remove the
   existing install.
4. Run setup with change/repair/remove options. All three fail with same error

So I am stuck. my ultimate goal is just to do a clean reinstall of the tool. I have looked for the procedure to perform a manual uninstall and haven't found one. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The full log file might be helpful.  Have you tried to delete the installation directory and try to install the application again?  Most applications keep their data contained to the installation directory and a user profile data directory both can be deleted manually.  ghost Registry entries are not as important as crooks like IOBit make it sound. Yes;  I believe IOBit to be crooks because of the shovelwear they try to sell people, registry cleaners, do more harm then good.

Comment: @Ramhound - deleting the installation did the trick. From there, the TortosieHG installer successfully finished the "Remove" option. Then I could do a clean re-install. If you put your comment into an answer I will mark it as the answer for this.

Comment: It's not worthy of being an answer, it basic troubleshooting 101, I can only post stuff in the 102 course

Comment: Try [my solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1123101/how-do-i-fix-a-corrupted-itunes-installation-on-windows-7/1291456#1291456).

Answer (score -1):

have you tried a third party application like [IObit](http://download.cnet.com/IObit-Uninstaller/3000-2096_4-75161625.html) his should do the trick.

Comment: All IObit does is launches the same uninstaller that Windows launches when you tell it you want to uninstall an application.

Comment: Thanks for the head's up, @Ramhound. I do not trust those things.